# Show Captcha for user to resolve in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a power-shell script for auto account creation. I want to grab the captcha, show it to the user and then wait for input. How can i achieve this in powershell? So far below is the script that i came up with.

```
$CreateAccount = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$CreateAccount.visible = $true  #this will be change to $false!
$CreateAccount.Navigate("https://www.test.com/account/create")

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5000; 

$CreateAccount.getElementByID("input_text_firstName").value = "TestFirstName"
$CreateAccount.getElementByID("input_text_lastName").value = "TestLastName"
$CreateAccount.getElementByID("input_email_uid").value = "Test@gmail.com"
$CreateAccount.getElementByID("input_email_uid").value = "Test@gmail.com"
$CreateAccount.getElementByID("input_tel_dateofbirthmonth").value = "1"
$CreateAccount.getElementByID("input_tel_dateofbirthday").value = "1"
$CreateAccount.getElementByID("input_tel_dateofbirthyear").value = "2001"
$CreateAccount.getElementById("input_password_password").checked= true;
```

Comment: It's kinda the whole point of a Captcha that a human does all the work. Trying to work around, even when a human really does some work, might run into bot countermeasures.

Comment: Yeah, i get it falls under the anti-bot sort of thing. What i am trying to do here is to automate what a website is doing/ presenting the captcha to the user so all he needs to do is enter an e-mail and solve the captcha rather than to fill the First, lastname, E-mail and password.